# Sum values in one column for all rows with matching data in another column, either through VBA or a combination of formulas/functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

My title needs explanation. Below is some sample data so I can explain what I'm looking for:

[image]

What I need is a formula, macro or function that will `sum` the **Duration values** in Column `C` for each of the **unique IP addresses**. Using the example above, cell `D2` would result in displaying the same as cell `C2` as there's only one duration value pertaining to the IP address in `A2`. However, cell `D6` would result in displaying the sum of the duration values in `C3:C6` as the IP address for each of these are identical in `A3:A6`.

So, in a nutshell I need the total sum of duration for each unique IP address. Ideally, for ease of reference, the `sum` will occur in the cell corresponding with the last row of each unique address rather than all cells in Column `D`. Below is an example of how this would look:

[image]

In the above sample cells `D3, D4, D5` and `D12` are blank, but I would be happy with another solution so long as I can easily identify the cells that have a summed duration in them.

I have played with a number of formulas using SUMIF, MATCH, INDEX but in all these cases I need to *specify* the IP address for them to work. Obviously, having to do this defeats the purpose.

I've also tried a combination of `IF` and `MAX`, but this only partly automates identifying which rows need to be summed, which isn't a huge time saver. For example, I tried:

```
=IF($C2=MAX(IF($A2=$A$2:$A$5630,$C$2:$C$5630,-1)),"Sum","")
```

The above formula does identify the rows I need to add the `SUM` formula in column `D`, but that's still a manual process to do the actual summing.

Any hints etc would be greatly appreciated as I have nine spreadsheets with thousands of rows of IP addresses and need a way to automate this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` and `SUMIF` ,Maybe you can try this:[image]

Comment: That works! And for a bonus, I actually understand it! :) Thank you so much!